# PLS-00382: expression is of wrong type In Block But Not For a type from package

Tags: plsql, plsqldeveloper, oracle19c

I am new to PL/SQL, I am trying to create a type of a table with %rowtype and followed by declaring a variable and doing sort of operations example; below is the code snippet of the logic that i am trying:

```
DECLARE
TYPE my_type IS TABLE OF emp%rowtype INDEX BY PLS_INTEGER;
l_arr_type  my_type;

BEGIN
    SELECT * BULK COLLECT INTO l_arr_type FROM emp;
FOR rec IN (SELECT * FROM TABLE (l_arr_type) ORDER BY HIREDATE)
        LOOP
           DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Ename is: '||rec.ENAME||' and hire date is: '||rec.HIREDATE);
        END LOOP;


END;
```

Error:

> ORA-06550: line 8, column 38: PLS-00382: expression is of wrong type

But same thing is working when i am declaring the variable inside a package and using the same; am I missing some thing here? Isn't not a strange behavior?
Below is the working code snippet:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE my_array IS
 TYPE my_type IS TABLE OF emp%rowtype INDEX BY PLS_INTEGER;
END my_array;
/

DECLARE
l_arr_type my_array.my_type;

BEGIN
    SELECT * BULK COLLECT INTO l_arr_type FROM emp;

    FOR rec IN (SELECT * FROM TABLE (l_arr_type) ORDER BY HIREDATE)
        LOOP
           DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Ename is: '||rec.ENAME||' and hire date is: '||rec.HIREDATE);
        END LOOP;


END;
```

It will be helpful if i can get a clarification behind this kind of behavior ;

------------------------update-----------------

Similar operation is working with TYPE as RECORD; below is my code snippet

```
DECLARE

TYPE my_type IS RECORD (ename_t emp.ENAME%TYPE, sal_t emp.SAL%TYPE, eno_t emp.empno%TYPE);
l_arr_type  my_type;

BEGIN
    SELECT ENAME, sal, empno  INTO l_arr_type FROM emp  where ename='KING';
           DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Ename is: '||l_arr_type.ename_t);
END;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQL is different than PL/SQL. They are processed by different engines and have a different set of recognized types. When you invoke a SQL statement within PL/SQL, you switch to the SQL engine and it operates without visibility to your code. For this reason, historically SQL could only navigate collections typed as SQL types (`create type ...`). PL/SQL types were inaccessible to it.

But starting in 12.1, Oracle began permitting the `TABLE` SQL operator to access PL/SQL collections, but requires them to be defined in *package headers*. Package headers are sort of like exposed object specifications that outside code, and now the SQL engine itself, can interrogate to understand how to access a PL/SQL object, including a collection.

Comment: thanks for this clarification yes it make sense to me :-)

Comment: when i am doing similar operation with RECORD , for TYPE as RECORD we are not seeing the same issue of scope in and out side the context switch, i had modified the question with the code snippet, what could be the reason behind this? Because as per my understanding in both the cases context switch is happening only once

Comment: @RitoSarkar, your first example was using `TABLE` against a collection. Your last example in your update isn't. The `INTO` clause is PL/SQL and doesn't have the type constraints that `TABLE` (which is SQL) has. `INTO` was never the problem, even in your first example.

Comment: Ok so is that mean 'SELECT * FROM TABLE (l_arr_type) '  this where the problem is?

Comment: @RitoSarkar, yes.